# How to convert a pandas value_counts into a python list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas series and I am taking its value count using `value_counts`.I  need to get it into a list. I tried `to_list()` but got error.

```
df['AAA'].value_counts(sort=True).to_list()
```

If I run, `df['AAA'].value_counts(sort=True)` , I will get something like

```
3    301
2    185
7     75
4     25
5     16
Name: AAA, dtype: int64
```

How to convert this into : `[301,185,75,25,16]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`tolist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) not `to_list()` (without `_`):

```
df['AAA'].value_counts(sort=True).tolist()
```